# Failed to find application object 'app' in 'main' - Heroku CLI

Tags: heroku, flask

I try to push code [from this GitHub repo](https://github.com/WillWammer/Image-Crawler) to my Heroku application, but I keep getting the same error, and my process keeps exiting with error 1. I've looked at these posts to solve my problems:

[gunicorn causing errors in heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352923/gunicorn-causing-errors-in-heroku)
[Flask app dont start on heroku server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754262/flask-app-dont-start-on-heroku-server)
[Python Flask heroku application error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019551/python-flask-heroku-application-error/42035883)

**main.py**

```
import os
import sys
import urllib.request
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect

ic = Flask(__name__)

count = 0


@ic.route("/")
def main():
    if count == 1:
        return render_template("index.html", result=str((str(count) + " Image Downloaded !")))
    else:
        return render_template("index.html", result=str((str(count) + " Images Downloaded !")))


@ic.route("/get_images", methods=['POST'])
def get_images():
    _url = request.form['inputURL']
    try:
        global count
        count = 0
        code = requests.get(_url)
        text = code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
        for img in soup.findAll('img'):
            count += 1
            if (img.get('src'))[0:4] == 'http':
                src = img.get('src')
            else:
                src = urljoin(_url, img.get('src'))
            download_image(src, count)
        return redirect("http://localhost:5000")
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as error:
        return render_template("index.html", result=str(error))


def download_image(url, num):
    try:
        image_name = str(num) + ".jpg"
        image_path = os.path.join("images/", image_name)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, image_path)
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid URL !")
    except:
        print("Unknown Exception" + str(sys.exc_info()[0]))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ic.run()
```

**Procfile**

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
web: gunicorn main:app
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run

```
gunicorn main:app
```

you're [telling `gunicorn`](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html) that your application's entry point is the `app` variable in th `main` module. You don't have an `app` variable; your Flask app is called `ic`.

You also don't need that `heroku ps:scale web=1` line. That's a command that you might run on your *local* machine to scale your `web` process type to one dyno.

Change your `Procfile` to say

```
web: gunicorn main:ic
```

commit and redeploy.